# show img src from mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

I wanna show image with `<img src="here a query" >`

Im doing my insert like that.

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO imagenez (ID, imagenes) VALUES (NULL, '{$_FILES['userfile']['name']}')");
```

And now i wanna take my picture for img.
its possible? if not, please a alternative way.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Where do you want to store the image?

Comment: Try being a bit more clear about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I wanna to show image in html. using a query.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider what will happen if a user uploads a picture with a filename like `s'); DROP TABLE imagenez; --`.

**Always** sanitize your inputs.

Comment: nothing will happen. mysql_query() sends a unique query (**multiple queries are not supported**), Of course, it has to be protected against sql injections.

Comment: i proved echo Header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");  but I have problem too.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new PHP page that displays the image.

```
<?php
//image.php

// connect to your DB

// get the image from the database
$image_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['ID']);
$sql = "SELECT imagenes FROM imagenez WHERE ID ='$image_id'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$image = mysql_result($result, 0);

// set the content header
//you may need to change this if you have different types of images
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
echo $image;
?>
```

Now in your HTML output, use the new page with the image id to display.

```
<img src="image.php?ID=12" />
```

Comment: It's better though if you store your images as a file in a separate directory instead of in the database. Then when you need to use them, just reference the image file directly. Your database table would hold (ID, FileName).

Comment: Yeah, i did like You said. but I have a problem.header('Content-Type: image/jpeg') is not working. I prove in text/html and its work. what is my problem?

Comment: If you get an error on header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); the most likely reason is you have already started output in the script. PHP can't set the HTTP headers once you start output. Make sure you don't have any empty spaces before the <?php.